# Silverlight - Image Not Loading from URI at Runtime?

Tags: c#, silverlight, image, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I've added an image element to my Silverlight app, and while the image pulls right up when in design mode, it doesn't load at all when running the app.

Code is:

```
<Image Height="95" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
       Margin="12,541,0,0" 
       Name="imgBannerAd" 
       Stretch="Fill" 
       VerticalAlignment="Top" 
       Width="828" 
       Source="http://myurl.com/images/theimage.png" 
       />
```

What's the deal? I'd tried running the file via the local hard drive and localhost, neither has any effect.

Answer (score 1):

I would check that

- you don't have a cross domain issue; [Peter Bromberg: Handling Cross-Domain Images and Gifs](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/c0046ba1-5df5-486a-8145-6b76a40ea43d/silverlight-handling-cro.aspx) and [Tim Heuer: Hosting cross-domain Silverlight applications](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/06/10/troubleshooting-debugging-silverlight-cross-domain-xap-hosting.aspx)
- some versions of Silverlight can have png image problems (never noticed this myself) [helpful link](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/139712/312117.aspx)

Comment: Cross-scheme is another consideration along the lines you're suggesting - this wouldn'y apply to the localhost case, but when running from file:// scheme, this explains a lot of weird things.

Comment: Turns out that the issue only occurs when the Silverlight project is loaded as a File:// - Is there any way in order to make Silverlight be able to grab items from the internet even when loaded from the desktop? I actually plan on distributing this app directly to the users, not hosting it on a server, so being able to have Silverlight access internet resources when loaded from a file saved to the computer is essential.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when you test your file using the Visual Studio generated test html file, loaded directly from disk.

If you create an Asp.Net application to host your Silverlight XAP, the problem should go away.